# Limite Utilizando o FOR XML PATH

Tags: sql, json, array, sql-server, transações

Estou montando um select, nele preciso que retorne um Json Array com mais de 1000 registros, porém utilizando o FOR XML PATH, percebi que o mesmo tem uma limitação no retorno da informação, cortando o meus dados. É possível aumentar esse limite ou existe alguma outra função que substitua essa? Abaixo essa minha query:

```
                 SELECT  REPLACE(''+( SELECT 

                '{"idLoja":'+RTRIM(CONVERT(bigint, CASE WHEN I.CODVEND = NULL THEN 22209 ELSE 22209 END ))+','+

                    '"departamento":"'+RTRIM(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),CATP.DESCRICAO))+'",'+ 

                    '"categoria":"'+RTRIM(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),CATP.DESCRICAO))+'",'+ 

                    '"subCategoria":"'+RTRIM(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),CATF.DESCRICAO))+'",'+ 

                    '"marca":"'+RTRIM(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),P.MARCA))+'",'+ 

                    '"unidade":"'+RTRIM(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),P.UNIDADE))+'",'+ 

                    '"volume":"'+RTRIM(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),'1'+P.UNIDADE))+'",'+ 

                    '"codigoBarra":"'+RTRIM(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),B.CODBARRA))+'",'+ 

                    '"nome":"'+RTRIM(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),I.NOME))+'",'+ 

                    '"valor":'+RTRIM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),I.VALOR))+','+ 

                    '"valorPromocao":'+RTRIM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),I.VALORPROMOCAO))+','+ 

                    '"quantidadeEstoqueAtual":'+RTRIM(CONVERT(int,2))+','+ 

                    '"descricao":"'+RTRIM(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),I.DESCPROD))+'",'+ 

                    '"ativo":"'+RTRIM(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),CASE WHEN I.ATIVO='S' THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END))+'",'+ 

                    '"plu":'+RTRIM(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),P.CODPROD))+'},',''

                 FROM AD_MKTPIFOOD I (NOLOCK)

                 LEFT JOIN SANKHYA.TGFPRO P             (NOLOCK) ON P.CODPROD   =   I.CODPROD
                 LEFT JOIN SANKHYA.AD_MARKETPLACE MKT   (NOLOCK) ON MKT.CODPROD =   I.CODPROD
                 LEFT JOIN SANKHYA.AD_CATEGORIEMGL CATF (NOLOCK) ON CATF.CODCATEGORIA = I.CODCATEGORIA
                 LEFT JOIN SANKHYA.AD_CATEGORIEMGL CATP (NOLOCK) ON CATF.CODCATEGORIAPAI = CATP.CODCATEGORIA
                 LEFT JOIN SANKHYA.TGFBAR B (NOLOCK) ON B.CODPROD = I.CODPROD

                WHERE I.CODPROD = MKT.CODPROD
                AND ISNULL(PRODENV ,'N') ='S'
                                     
                FOR XML PATH ('') ) +']',',]','') AS produtos
```

Abaixo está um resultado do meu select, ele está resumido, pois ficou grande, ele corta o final.

`{"idLoja":22209,"departamento":"PERFUMARIA","categoria":"PERFUMARIA","subCategoria":"HIDRATANTE","marca":"D-LINK","unidade":"CM","volume":"1CM","codigoBarra":"7898594000017","nome":"TESTE ENVIO PRODUTO HOMOLOGACAO 3","valor":12.99,"valorPromocao":12.99,"quantidadeEstoqueAtual":2,"descricao":"TESTE ENVIO PRODUTO HOMOLOGACAO 3","ativo":"true","plu":10052},{"idLoja":22209,"departamento":"PERFUMARIA","categoria":"PERFUMARIA","subCategoria":"HIDRATANTE","marca":"D-LINK","unidade":"CM","volume":"1CM","codigoBarra":"7898594000154","nome":"TESTE ENVIO PRODUTO HOMOLOGACAO 4","valor":12.99,"valorPromocao":12.99,"quantidadeEstoqueAtual":2,"descricao":"TESTE ENVIO PRODUTO HOMOLOGACAO 4","ativo":"true","plu":10062}`

Encontrei uma outra maneira de formar esse Json, porém ele está quebrando o objeto por linha, ao invés de inserir tudo em uma única linha.

```
OUTER APPLY (SELECT 
                    valueList.idLoja,
                    valueList.departamento,
                    valueList.categoria,
                    valueList.subCategoria,
                    valueList.marca,
                    valueList.unidade,
                    valueList.volume,
                    valueList.codigoBarra,
                    valueList.nome,
                    valueList.valor,
                    valueList.valorPromocao,
                    valueList.quantidadeEstoqueAtual,
                    valueList.descricao,
                    valueList.ativo,
                    valueList.plu


                FROM (SELECT
                        RTRIM(CONVERT(bigint, CASE WHEN I.CODVEND = NULL THEN 22209 ELSE 22209 END )) AS idLoja,
                        RTRIM(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),CATP.DESCRICAO)) AS departamento,
                        RTRIM(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),CATP.DESCRICAO))AS categoria,
                        RTRIM(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),CATF.DESCRICAO)) AS subCategoria,
                        RTRIM(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),P.MARCA)) AS marca,
                        RTRIM(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),P.UNIDADE)) AS unidade,
                        RTRIM(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),'1'+P.UNIDADE)) AS volume,
                        RTRIM(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),B.CODBARRA))AS codigoBarra,
                        RTRIM(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),I.NOME)) AS nome,
                        RTRIM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),I.VALOR)) AS valor,
                        RTRIM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),I.VALORPROMOCAO)) AS valorPromocao,
                        RTRIM(CONVERT(int,2)) AS quantidadeEstoqueAtual,
                        RTRIM(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),I.DESCPROD))AS descricao,
                        RTRIM(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),CASE WHEN I.ATIVO='S' THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END)) AS ativo,
                        RTRIM(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),P.CODPROD)) AS plu
                        
                                                              
                    WHERE I.CODPROD = P.CODPROD) 
                    
                    AS valueList FOR JSON AUTO) AS cubagemList(produtos)
```

Mas está trazendo o seguinte resultado, o objeto está quebrando por linha, deveriam trazer igual na ultima imagem, vários objetos em uma única linha.

[image: Evidência do Resultado]

[image: Deveria Trazer Nesse Formato]

Deveria Trazer Nesse Formato

O que pode estar faltando?

Comment: Msg 174, Level 15, State 1, Line 27
The replace function requires 3 argument(s).
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 100
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

Comment: acabei de editar o código da resposta abaixo, foi removido um fechamento de parênteses que estava sobrando

Comment: sobre essa alternativa com o For JSON que você tentou, tente utiliza-lo fora do operador Apply, pois dentro do Apply será gerado um JSON para cada linha retornada pelo Apply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem funções específicas para JSon a partir do SQL Server 2016, mas seguindo a forma como você tentou experimente especificar o tipo de dados do resultado para ver se resolve a questão do truncamento:

```
FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE).value('.', 'varchar(max)')  +']',',]','') AS produtos
```